# justify-content по правому боку не распологает

Tags: html, css

во флексе `justify-content: flex-end;` не работает, т.е. блоки всё равно находятся в левом краю.

```css
.intro_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro_content">
  <h1 class="intro_title">
    We Design and Develop
  </h1>
  <div class="intro_text">
    We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.
  </div>
  <div class="intro_button">
    Contact us
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: разметка сломалась, поправь

Comment: `align-items: flex-end` для `flex-direction: column`

Comment: Соответственно для `flex-direction: row` будет `justify-content: flex-end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз Вы поменяли направление со стандартного row на column, то теперь надо задавать не justify-content, а align-items:

```css
.intro_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro_content">
  <h1 class="intro_title">
    We Design and Develop
  </h1>
  <div class="intro_text">
    We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.
  </div>
  <div class="intro_button">
    Contact us
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Потому что `flex-direction: column;`, то есть в столбик.
Чтобы было в строку - надо `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: а если человеку нужен именно column? :))

Comment: Если column, то элементы внутри display:flex будут располагаться сверху вниз. Тогда flex-end - это последний элемент, то есть в данном случае самый нижний.

Comment: и? Вы вопрос-то поняли? человеку надо, чтобы контент был column и при этом по правому краю располагался